# Redirecting screen output from cell phone to monitor screen

Tags: android, maemo

Is there any way to redirect cell phone output to a standard screen?

Would it be possible on Linux & X-server based devices - like Maemo? And on Android devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least N900 has video-out capability over the headphone/microphone jack, so you can plug into your TV (or anything that takes composite video) if you will. Also, you can install the package [x11vnc](https://garage.maemo.org/projects/x11vnc/) on a maemo device to achieve this for on a computer.

Comment: The accepted answer is this because I had not thought about Maemo, but both of the, are fine!